# Sending Email in Future with specific condition - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I'm developing application using third party payment gateway to accept bank transfer. 
The bank transfer is going to expire within 6 hours if the payment gateway don't receive any transfer from customer. 
I want to send reminder email 1 hour before the expiration time.

At the moment, I'm using task scheduling every 15 minutes to check my transaction tables one by one. The transaction is growing and will be million transaction per day in short time.

This approach is not great because cron job is consuming huge memory and not effective. I need some advice to optimize the approach. Can anyone shed the light?

Answer (score 0):

You want an additional table for all "pending" transactions. This way your cron job only reads pending transactions. Once the transaction has been completed, or it has expired, you remove the entry from the "pending" table.

The "pending" table would have only the few fields that necessary to know if the transfer is still pending. When reading this table you would "join" it to the main table to retrieve the rest of the information.